# Profile doesn't update everywhere if I remove a website link

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

Steps:

1. Create profiles on multiple Stack Exchange sites with a website link everywhere.
2. Go to one of the sites, edit your profile, remove the website link, Click save.

Expected: The website link is supposed to be removed from all the linked profiles on SE network sites.

Observed: The website link is removed only from the profile you edit.